# How to install multiple versions of the same package

Tags: apt, dependencies, versions

Two pieces of software that I need on my system have dependencies for `libfltk1.1-dev` and `libfltk1.3-dev`. I tried installing both, as when I installed one, it would remove the other. So I typed this command into the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libfltk1.1-dev libfltk1.3-dev
```

And I got this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libfltk1.1-dev : Conflicts: libfltk-dev
  libfltk1.3-dev : Conflicts: libfltk-dev
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Can I/How do I install both?

Comment: Do you mean that a single application needs both `libfltk1.1-dev` and `libfltk1.3-dev`?

Comment: No two different applications. One needs one and the other needs the other.

Comment: In that case, you only need one. One a program is compiled, you no longer need to have the corresponding `-dev` package; instead you need the shared library version (which should be automatically installed). Therefore, once you compile one of the programs, remove the package and install the other package.

Answer (score 6):

No, both `libfltk1.1-dev` and `libfltk1.3-dev` cannot be installed at the same time. This is because the headers (among other files) in both packages are installed at the same location and therefore would be conflicting.

Edit: Since these are two different programs, the following steps can be followed:

1. Install `libfltk1.1-dev`.
2. Compile the program that needs `libfltk1.1-dev`.
3. Remove `libfltk1.1-dev`, but make sure `libfltk1.1` is kept.
4. Install `libfltk1.3-dev`.
5. Compile the program that needs `libfltk1.3-dev`.
6. (Optional) Remove `libfltk1.3-dev`, but make sure `libfltk1.3` is kept.

The reason this works is that the `-dev` packages (which depend on the corresponding shared library package) contain the headers needed to *compile* a program, but are not needed to *run* the program. The shared library package contains the actual library that is needed to *run* the program, and so this package has to be installed to run the program.

Comment: Such a superior system for managing packages