# Remove a package without removing some part of it?

Tags: apt, package-management, debian, versions

I was looking for a way to install 2 version of the same package, (qt5-default and qt5-dev). i found similar issue [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499112/how-to-install-multiple-versions-of-the-same-package/499145#499145?newreg=0e6d1d57e4274c33b2b989bc43a0d0b8)

and one of the answer was

> Remove libfltk1.1-dev, but make sure libfltk1.1 is kept.

by saiarcot895

I don't really understand how can you remove it but keeping it also? I guess in that question context, libfltk1.1 is needed for the app run time and libfltk1.1-dev was needed for the compiling. but if i do such "sudo apt-get remove libfltk1.1-dev", it will also remove libfltk1.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`libfltk1.1` is not "part of" `libfltk1.1-dev`, they are separate packages.

`libfltk1.1-dev` *depends on* `libfltk1.1` but not vice versa (you can confirm this using `apt depends`) so you may remove the `-dev` package without affecting the run-time package:

```
$ sudo apt remove libfltk1.1-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libfltk1.1-dev
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 269 not upgraded.
After this operation, 2,290 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
(Reading database ... 404888 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libfltk1.1-dev (1.1.10-23) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
$
$ apt policy libfltk1.1 libfltk1.1-dev
libfltk1.1:
  Installed: 1.1.10-23
  Candidate: 1.1.10-23
  Version table:
 *** 1.1.10-23 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
libfltk1.1-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.1.10-23
  Version table:
     1.1.10-23 500
        500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```